# PostgreSQL: Extract column into separate table and update other column with related key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `product` with column `product_image_path`.  These parts of the data need to be moved to a related table, `image`, which has a separate column `image_path` and a surrogate key `id`.  The tables are related through the foreign key `product.image_id`.  Is there a way to insert all values of `product_image_path` into the `image` table and immediately update the `product.image_id` to refer to the rows that were just created?

This has to be done in SQL or PL/pgSQL as it is part of a series of database migrations, which do not allow arbitrary scripting.

```
product:
 id | product_image_path     
----+-------------------
  1 | foo.jpg
  2 | bar.jpg
  3 | foo.jpg
```

Should become:

```
product:
id | image_id
---+---------
1  | 1
2  | 2
3  | 3

image:
id | image_path
---+-----------
1  | foo.jpg
2  | bar.jpg
3  | foo.jpg
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, both before and after versions. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: @jarlh I have now added some sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the new image id can be the same as the product id, this is quite easy:

Create the new table:

```
create table image (id serial primary key, image_path text);
```

Copy the data from the product table:

```
insert into image (id, image_path)
select id, product_image_path
from product;
```

Adjust the sequence for the `image.id` column:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('image', 'id'), (select max(id) from image));
```

Add the new image_id column and populate it:

```
alter table product add image_id integer;
update product set image_id = id;
```

Get rid of the old_column:

```
alter table product drop product_image_path;
```